# Binning into timeslots - Is there a better way than using list comp?

Tags: python

I have a dataset of events (tweets to be specific) that I am trying to bin / discretize. The following code seems to work fine so far (assuming 100 bins):

```
HOUR = timedelta(hours=1)
start = datetime.datetime(2009,01,01)
z = [dt + x*HOUR for x in xrange(1, 100)]
```

But then, I came across this fateful line at python docs 'This makes possible an idiom for clustering a data series into n-length groups using `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)`'. The zip idiom does indeed work - but I can't understand how (what is the `*` operator for instance?). How could I use to make my code prettier? I'm guessing this means I should make a generator / iterable for time that `yields` the time in graduations of an HOUR?

Comment: See [section "Calls" in the python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls) for the star.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will try to explain `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` in terms of a simpler example:

imagine you have the list `s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

`iter(s)` gives you a `listiterator` object that will yield the next number from `s` each time you ask for an element.

`[iter(s)] * n` gives you the list with `iter(s)` in it *n* times e.g. `[iter(s)] * 2 = [<listiterator object>, <listiterator object>]` - the key here is that these are 2 references to the *same* iterator object, not 2 distinct iterator objects.

`zip` takes a number of sequences and returns a list of tuples where each tuple contains the *ith* element from each of the sequences. e.g.  `zip([1,2], [3,4], [5,6]) = [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]` where `(1, 3, 5)` are the first elements from the parameters passed to `zip` and `(2, 4, 6)` are the second elements from the parameters passed to `zip`.

The `*` in front of `*[iter(s)]*n` converts the `[iter(s)]*n` from being a list into being multiple parameters being passed to `zip`. so if `n` is 2 we get `zip(<listiterator object>, <listiterator object>)`

`zip` will request the next element from each of its parameters but because these are both references to the same iterator this will result in `(1, 2)`, it does the same again resulting in `(3, 4)` and again resulting in `(5, 6)` and then there are no more elements so it stops. Hence the result `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]`. This is the clustering a data series into n-length groups as mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

The expression from the docs looks like this:

```
zip(*[iter(s)]*n)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
it = iter(s)
zip(*[it, it, ..., it]) # n times
```

The `[...]*n` repeats the list `n` times, and this results in a list that contains `n`references to the same iterator.

This is again equal to:

```
it = iter(s)
zip(it, it, ..., it)    # turning a list into positional parameters
```

The `*` before the list turns the list elements into positional parameters of the function call.

Now, when zip is called, it starts from left to right to call the iterators to obtain elements that should be grouped together. Since all parameters refer to the same iterator, this yields the first `n` elements of the initial sequence. Then that process continues for the second group in the resulting list, and so on.

The result is the same as if you had constructed the list like this (evaluated from left to right):

```
it = iter(s)
[(it.next(), it.next(), ..., it.next()), (it.next(), it.next(), ..., it.next()),  ...]
```